# How to use svn with beyond compare 3

Tags: svn, beyondcompare

I want to use svn command line with beyond compare and get the following output

```
Text Compare
Produced: 11/16/2008 11:45:34 AM

SourceFile,CompareFile,IOriginal,IAdded,IDeleted,IChanged,UOriginal,UAdded,UDeleted,UChanged
"E:\Downloads\eeli\eel\1.c","E:\Downloads\eeli\eel\2.c",967,192,501,270,368,113,205,89
```

What is the exact commandline?

Comment: why would anyone vote this down ? I know nothing about "beyond compare" but people actually use/know it and have already answered the question ? the question is not too vague or bizzare, no obvius spelling errors ? What's happening.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put this in (for example) c:\bin\bcsvn.bat

```
@REM To configure this as the Subversion diff command, add these lines to
@REM    c:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Subversion\config:
@REM
@REM [helpers]
@REM diff-cmd = c:\bin\bcsvn.bat
@REM
@"C:\Progra~1\Beyond~1\bcomp.exe" "%6" /title1=%3 "%7" /title2=%5
@exit 0
```

You'll might have to fix up the path to bcomp.exe.

Answer (score 20):

All the Beyond Compare settings for different version control systems are outlined here: http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php?c=kb_vcs

For TortoiseSVN try https://web.archive.org/web/20221130064351/https://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#tortoisesvn

Answer (score 3):

The instructions suggested by the others didn't work for me. Here's how I finally got it:

I. On a Windows Explorer window, Right-click > TortoiseSVN > Settings

1. Diff Viewer
2. External
3. `...`

   [image: The first three steps]
4. Find `BCompare.exe`. If you did a normal installation it's in `C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4\`.

   *There's no need to enter all the whacky variables outlined in the documentation, in fact I couldn't get it to work with those.*
5. Go ahead and do the same thing for the other options in Diff Viewer and Merge Tool if you want.

### *Here's what the final should look like:*

[image]