# What are the arguments passed to SVNs --diff3-cmd?

Tags: svn, diff

I have been trying to write my own diff3 wrap script for SVN and I am wondering what the various parameters that get passed to `--diff3-cmd` are.

The closest thing I could find so far is:

[How can I use Beyond Compare 3 as the diff3-cmd for svn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028694/how-can-i-use-beyond-compare-3-as-the-diff3-cmd-for-svn)

But it doesn't quite explain what all of the parameters do.

I also tried to pass it through this:

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "$*"
```

as `--diff3-cmd`, and got some output, but I cant make heads or tails of the arguments it spit out. Are these the standard args for some unix diff command?

```
-E -m -L .working -L .merge-left.r1000 -L .merge-right.r1001 /home/user/some/long/filename1 /tmp/tmp /home/user/some/long/filename2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the [appropriate section](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html#svn.advanced.externaldifftools.diff3) in the SVN Book?

Comment: Aha, apparently I missed this section. Thanks!

Comment: there is a better answer below

Answer (score 5):

> Are these the standard args for some
>   unix diff command?

Yes, these are parameters for [GNU diff3](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/diff3-Options.html#diff3%20Options). It's [covered in the svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html).

This is what they actually represent:

1. `-E` - Add brackets to the diff output. e.g. `<<<<<<< mine`
2. `-m` - [Output the merge file directly](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html%5Fnode/Bypassing-ed.html#Bypassing-ed)
3. `-L` - [Same as `--label`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=diff3&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%206.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&format=html) Give a name to the files.
4. `.working` - Label name for the working copy file.
5. `-L` - [Same as `--label`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=diff3&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%206.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&format=html) Give a name to the files.
6. `.merge-left.rXXX` - Label name that is the revision number of the older revision.
7. `-L` - [Same as `--label`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=diff3&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%206.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&format=html) Give a name to the files.
8. `.merge-right.rXXX` - Label name that is the revision number of the newer revision.
9. `<temp-file-path>` - File path to the 'mine' file. i.e. [the working copy *before* the update process](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.mergeconflicts)
10. `<temp-file-path>` - File path to the 'older' file. i.e. the older revision
11. `<temp-file-path>` - File path to the 'yours' file. i.e. the newer revision

As you can see, the first 2 are not relevant to anything other than GNU diff3, so when writing a bat file to pass the parameters to an external tool use `SHIFT` twice so you have the relevant parameters in slots 1-9 and not 3-11.

This is necessary for batch files as they only handle 9 parameters but is not necessary for bash/python etc.